# pandas combing dataframes optimisation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

Hey I have a time series order dataset in pandas with missing values for some dates to correct it I am trying to pick up the value from the previous dates available.

```
for date in dates_missing:
    df_temp = df[df.order_date<date].sort_values(['order_date'],ascending=False)
    supplier_map = df_temp.groupby('supplier_id')['value'].first()

    for supplier_id in supplier_map.index.values:
        df[(df.order_datetime==date)&(df.su_id == supp)]['value'] = supplier_map.get(supplier_id)
```

To explain the code I am looping over the missing dates then fetching the list of values previous to the missing date.
Then getting the supplier id to value map using the pandas first()

> **NOW the slowest part is updating back the original data frame**

I am looping over each supplier and updating the values in the original data frame.

***Need suggestion to speed up this inner for loop***

Example:

`|order_date|supplier_id   |value |sku_id|
 |2017-12-01| 10           | 1.0  | 1    |
 |2017-12-01|  9           | 1.3  | 7    |
 |2017-12-01|  3           | 1.4  | 2    |
 |2017-12-02|  3           | 0    | 2    |
 |2017-12-02|  9           | 0    | 7    |
 |2017-12-03|  3           | 1.0  | 2    |
 |2017-12-03| 10           | 1.0  | 1    |
 |2017-12-03|  9           | 1.3  | 7    |`

date to fix 2017-12-02

`|2017-12-02|  3           | 0    | 2    |
 |2017-12-02|  9           | 0    | 7    |`

corrected data frame

`|order_date|supplier_id   |value |sku_id|
 |2017-12-01| 10           | 1.0  | 1    |
 |2017-12-01|  9           | 1.3  | 7    |
 |2017-12-01|  3           | 1.4  | 2    |
 |2017-12-02|  3           | 1.4  | 2    |
 |2017-12-02|  9           | 1.3  | 7    |
 |2017-12-03|  3           | 1.0  | 2    |
 |2017-12-03| 10           | 1.0  | 1    |
 |2017-12-03|  9           | 1.3  | 7    |`

PS:
I might not be way clear with the question so would be happy to answer doubts and re-edit the post moving on.

Comment: is your date is missing in a row or some values associated with the date are missing, can you clairify ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with some sample data and your expected output? Without seeing how your missing data is actually represented, it's difficult to provide a real answer.

Comment: Why not use pd.interpolate ?

Comment: @NagaKiran the data are rows but for certain dates values are zero

Comment: @AnnaIliukovich-StrakovskaiaI guess lack of example let to confusion provide one for clear context

Answer (score 0):

You can group the dataframe by day and supplier_id, for each grouped dataframe replace 0 with Null, once you got null fill with forward fill, for early values you can use backward fill,

It may reduce your time

```
df.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)
df['values'] = df.groupby([df.supplier_id])['values'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(0,np.nan).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill'))
```

Out:

```
    order_date  sku_id  supplier_id values
0   2017-12-01  1   10  1.0
1   2017-12-01  7   9   1.3
2   2017-12-01  2   3   1.4
3   2017-12-02  2   3   1.4
4   2017-12-02  7   9   1.3
5   2017-12-03  2   3   1.0
6   2017-12-03  1   10  1.0
7   2017-12-03  7   9   1.3
```